# How can I improve the tcp connection performance?

Tags: java, performance, spring, spring-integration

I have the following code:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" host="${netSocketServer}" port="${netPort}"
    single-use="true" so-timeout="${netSoTimeOut}" />

<int:channel id="input" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="input" reply-channel="reply" connection-factory="client"
    request-timeout="${netRequestTimeout}" reply-timeout="${netReplyTimeout}" />


<int:channel id="reply" datatype="java.lang.String" />
```

I must speed up my connection with other server.
Can I make an inprove on that code?

I log the following connection times to make me think abount the slow connection.

```
Waiting time was: 5985
Waiting time was: 6015
Waiting time was: 1578, 
Waiting time was: 5610, 
Waiting time was: 5735, 
Waiting time was: 1734, 
Waiting time was: 1797, 
Waiting time was: 1515, 
Waiting time was: 1469, 
Waiting time was: 6003, 
Waiting time was: 6656
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't force TCP to go faster.

Comment: What makes you think your TCP is too slow?

Comment: I log the connection time.

Comment: If you ping the remote server, what are your ping times?  What about traceroute?  If your connection times above are strictly network times, and don't include any other code, then I would say the problem is your network, not your code.

Comment: You need to provide much more information - like how many concurrent threads etc are being used, how big are the message; what is the network speed, etc. Use `WireShark` or similar to get a network trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided the units.

If they're milliseconds you have a serious network problem unrelated to your Spring-Integration config.

If they're microseconds, that looks normal, there's nothing wrong.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was a network problem related to excessive use of the network. Thanks!